# Best way to iterate through bit vectors as Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, iteration, bit, bitvector

Previously when I have iterated through bit vectors, I would use strings such as "0001", "0010", "0011", etc. I would parse base 10 integers into string representations with the correct base using Java, however I ran out of memory quickly.

Using C, I am looking for a way to iterate through bit vectors of a set length. If there is a length of 4, I would call int array[4] and use a for loop to fill each position with 0's to start. My trouble begins when I need to add numbers, going from [0,0,0,0] to [0,0,1,0], and so on and so forth until the condition of [1,1,1,1] is met.

I tried this code below.

```
int array[4];
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  array[i] = 0;
}
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  for(x=0; x<4; x++)
   {
     if (array[4-x] == 0 && (4-x) != 1)
      {
        array = array;
      }
     if (array[4-x] == 1)
      {
        array[4-x] == 0;
        array[4-x +1] ==1;
      }
   }
}
```

but this is not correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `==` is comparison. `=` is assignment.

Comment: `array[4 - x]` when x == 0 is an access out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: Also, what is the intention behind `array = array;`? On the whole, if you're trying to get a base-2 string representation of a number, math might be a better way to go about it, especially if memory is a concern.

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to do. If in Java you "ran out of memory quickly" by using string representations of base 10 integers, you'll have trouble even earlier in C, using arrays of integers to represent bits.

Comment: `0b0000` to `0b1111` are just integers from `0` to `15`. If the ith bit is set, then `x & (1 << i)` is not zero. You don't need an array to store 4 bits if they easily fit in a single byte. Perhaps you should clarify what you are trying to do, because this seems like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your approach was wrong in Java, and it seems wrong in C too.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `uint64_t` from `<inttypes.h>` (which includes the `<stdint.h>` where they are actually defined), for up to 64 bits.

If we number bits from 0 to 63, with 0 being the least significant bit, then bit *i* corresponds to numerical value 2<sup>*i*</sup>. (2<sup>0</sup> = 1, 2<sup>1</sup> = 2, 2<sup>2</sup> = 4, 2<sup>3</sup> = 8, 2<sup>4</sup> = 16, and so on.)

To test if a specific bit is set (nonzero) or clear (zero), we can use

```
static inline int  bit_is_set(const uint64_t  value, const int  bit)
{
    return !!(value & (((uint64_t)1) << bit));
}

static inline int  bit_is_clear(const uint64_t  value, const int  bit)
{
    return !(value & (((uint64_t)1) << bit));
}
```

The above return True (1), if the bit is set/clear, and False (0) otherwise.

(`!` is the Not operator, logical inverse. The `!!` is the Not-Not operator. If `x` is an arithmetic expression or numerical value, `!!x` is 0 if `x` is 0, and 1 if `x` is nonzero. It looks funny, but remember, it just keeps zero zero, and converts nonzero to 1. Quite useful.)

To change an individual bit, we can use

```
static inline uint64_t  set_bit(const uint64_t  value, const int  bit)
{
    return value | (((uint64_t)1) << bit);
}

static inline uint64_t  clear_bit(const uint64_t  value, const int  bit)
{
    return value & (~(((uint64_t)1) << bit));
}

static inline uint64_t  flip_bit(const uint64_t  value, const int  bit)
{
    return value ^ (((uint64_t)1) << bit);
}
```

In C, parameters are passed by value, so the parameter itself is unchanged: the functions return the value with the specified bit set/cleared/flipped (changed).

You can use

```
    printf("value is now %" PRIu64 ".\n", value);
```

to print an `uint64_t value;`.

To parse command-line parameters to `uint64_t`s, I use something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t  a, b;
    char      dummy;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help | help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s A B\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program calculates the binary OR of A and B.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %" SCNu64 " %c", &a, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not a 64-bit unsigned integer.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %" SCNu64 " %c", &b, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Not a 64-bit unsigned integer.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("A = %" PRIu64 "\n", a);
    printf("B = %" PRIu64 "\n", b);
    printf("A | B = %" PRIu64 "\n", a | b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Do note that the scanf() family of functions does not error on overflow. That means that if you supply `11111111111111111111111111111111`, it will be shown as something else, typically `18446744073709551615` (= `UINT64_MAX`).

There are ways to avoid that, the simplest being writing your own parser function, but if you always output the input variables (like the example program above does), you can assume the user will check, and not worry about it in typical cases.